# PHP: class "MongoClient" not found?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, php-5.6

I have this problem when i try to do 
`app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update` on the terminal :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
>     Attempted to load class "MongoClient" from the global namespace.
>     Did you forget a "use" statement?

I tried everything I found.
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: have you added `extension=mongodb.so` to your `php.ini` file?

Comment: Make sure your intl extension is activated in your php.ini. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Please note that `\MongoClient` comes from legacy driver called `mongo` (https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) and you need to install it, not current `mongodb` (note `db` difference by the end)

Comment: @TeyimPila `extension=mongodb.so` wasn't in the file php.ini, I added it but it still does not work.

Comment: @BilalAhmed It was not present so I added it but it does not work

Answer (score 3):

I can see you're using Doctrine MongoDB ODM. Doctrine MongoDB ODM relies on legacy mongo driver `ext-mongo`, that is available only to PHP up to 5.6. If you're using PHP up to 5.6 you just have to install and enable it.

If you're using PHP7+ you have to install the new mongo driver `ext-mongodb` and use a polyfill to bridge the Doctrine MongoDB ODM with the new library, as stated here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html#using-php-7

> You can use Doctrine MongoDB ODM with PHP 7, but there are a few extra steps during the installation. Since the legacy driver (referred to as ext-mongo) is not available on PHP 7, you will need the new driver (ext-mongodb) installed and use a polyfill to provide the API of the legacy driver.